# Javascript post timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, timeout, crossrider

Problem description: 
I'm making a post request inside of $.each loop:

```
$.each(companies, function() {
    appAPI.request.post({
        url: url,
        postData: postdata,
        onSuccess: onSuccess(),
        onFailure: onFailure()
    });
})
```

The syntax (I'm using crossrider.com API) is similar to jQuery, but still different - 'post' method doesn't have 'timeout' option. How can I check if it takes more than 3 seconds to receive a response, and if it is - abandon this request (don't call onSuccess() function)?

jQuery here can be used too, but I have to do appAPI.request.post instead of $.post for some reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the boolean variable. e.g. `isThreeSecElapsed` and set it true in OnSuccess & Failure. 
 You will also have to use the `setInterval` from javascript which will keep on reading `isThreeSecElapsed` until 3 seconds. If it is not set to true after 3 seconds. You can do your required code there. 
 You can wirte `return` directly at start of your Success method so that operations inside it will not be executed.